# how to share image on instagram from native app ios 9.2?

Tags: objective-c, instagram, ios9.2

**i have tried this code but it shows error like**

> Warning: Attempt to present <_UIDocumentActivityViewController:
>   0x16acdc00>  on  which is already
>   presenting <_UIDocumentActivityViewController: 0x16ae4800>

**how to solve this??**

```
-(IBAction)saveToInstagram:(id)sender {


        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
        NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.ig"];

        NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
        NSLog(@"JPG path %@", jpgPath);
        NSLog(@"URL Path %@", igImageHookFile);
        self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
        self.docFile = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
        self.docFile=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
        }



}
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
    return interactionController;
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerWillPresentOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that while the first docfile is being presented you try to present the second one

```
// First presentation
[self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {

        // Second presentation
        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ]; 
}
```

I don't really understand why do you need to use the same method twice, but if you really do, then for the first presentation use animated: NO. I would suggest some kind of completion code block, but it appears that there is no such method for `UIDocumentInteractionController`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add instagram in you plist array with key: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

```
        @property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *docIC;        

        - (void)sharePhoto:(UIImage *)image caption:(NSString *)caption
        {
            NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
            {
                NSString *imgPath = [TUtil documentPath:@"Image.igo"];
                NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
                [data writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];
                
                
                NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath];
                self.docIC = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
                [self.docIC setDelegate:self];
                [self.docIC setUTI:@"com.instagram.exclusivegram"];
                
                // Subject
                [self.docIC setName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]];
                
                //http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing
                //self.docIC.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:caption, @"InstagramCaption", nil];
                
                [self.docIC presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id389801252?mt=8";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
            }
        }
```